# How to model UI behaviors in UML

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml

I have two questions:

1 - Should we model UI behaviors??

2 - In what diagram should we model the UI behaviors? For example, a button should be Enabled or Disabled based on the user state (whether he is logged in or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uml state diagrams are useful for defining button state by diagrammatically

would you pls go through this link for [more info](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+8.+State+Diagrams/When+to+Use+State+Diagrams/)

Answer (score 0):

You can model a relevant set of UI use cases, and the sequence diagram is the perfect choice

Comment: so we should model the UI behaviors always?

Answer (score 0):

You can model UI in the Class diagram as well as the sequence diagram. I have an example where I used the UI class in a class diagram but it might not be the same for your case. This was a web-based project (J2EE MVC).

The rough sequence is: The system is initialized -> it creates the UI for each of the pages and also the controller for the pages -> the main homepage is displayed.

The UI pages were an important part of the level 1 Sequence diagram and had to be there in the class diagram.

To draw proper UML, always take into account a Domain diagram of your problem and a use-case document. The Domain diagram gives you the flow of data (objects) and the use-case document gives you the events.